# Append to div if no class or ID

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to create an iFrame within a page, but I do not know the parent's details e.g. a class name or ID, or anything.

Can I create the iFrame without knowing this information?

I tried the following but get the error `HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy`:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');       
iframe.src = 'http://myURL.com/embed/whatever/1213';       
window.parent.document.appendChild(iframe);
```

**UPDATE** To clarify, I'm asking if the iframe can be created this way within a div, within a page, not at the end of the body.

I know I can do

```
<iframe src="whatever"></iframe>
```

But I'd rather a javascript solution

Comment: Assuming - same domain - `window.parent.document.body.appendChild(iframe);`

Comment: or `document.body.appendChild(iframe)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the appending code to :

```
window.parent.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Because, `iframe` is also just another document internally, so you cannot append a document to a document.

If you want to append it to a div with id "iframeDiv", then you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("iframeDiv").appendChild(iframe);
```

But you can append it to `<body>`

Comment: Updated question although I'm thinking now the answer is probably no

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, everything you create in html is inside `<body>` What do you mean by "after" body?

Comment: Sorry, I meant not at the end of the body but in a specific place

Comment: Thanks, but thats the whole point, I do not and will never know the parent, so what i need is something like  this.parent.div.appendChild('iframe')